# MySQL gives syntax error "unexpected IF" when If else control statement is in query window

Tags: mysql, if-statement, mysql-workbench

I was using Microsoft SQL server before. I want to use some control statements like basic 'If else' in MySQL. When the below command is given in a query window

```
IF  3 <>4 THEN
Select * from EntityList_Base;
END IF
```

in MySQL workbench , it said "Unexpected IF" syntax error. Google results give `if else` examples used inside stored procedures, triggers etc.,
Is it not possible to use the control flow statements in a query window without using stored procedures like microsoft sql server? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I shall stop Googling then.
But what is the best way to test? Create a stored procedure itself?

Comment: Either this or simply having a look in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move the condition to the `WHERE` clause of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM EntityList_Base
WHERE 3<>4 AND other_conditions_here;
```

If the condition is false, the query will return no rows.